# iPhone - UIImagePickerController take screen shots?

Tags: iphone, uiimagepickercontroller, screen-capture

I am trying to use the following code to take screen shots from my uiimagePickerController

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imagePicker.view.bounds.size);
[self.imagePicker.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

It shows everything except what is capturing from the camera, i see the cancel button, take photo buttom.
Instead of what is displaying on the camera it's capturing a black screen, is there any way around this? or a better way to automatically capture an image from camera every 1 seconds?

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput 
didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer 
       fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
{ 
    UIImage *image = [self imageFromSampleBuffer:sampleBuffer];
    UIImageView *img = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    [img setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
    [self.view addSubview:img];
    [img release];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the new (in OS 4) AVFoundation APIs.

Try this page for some info:

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/qa/qa2010/qa1702.html

Comment: thanks, it seems to be the best way, but o far the data i receive cannot be converted to a uiimage. I'll update

Comment: The sample code in the link I posted should help. Part way down is a line that says < Add your code here that uses the image >. At that point yiu have a uiimage to do what you like with.

Comment: Yes everything works fine and i receive captureOutput, but when i convert it to a uiimage and create an imageview and add it to my view, the uiimageview doesn't display the picture, i think somehow the data is interrupted. Does this suppose to work on iphone 3g? since iphone 3g doesn't allow video recording.

Comment: the problem is that it's blocking the main thread, so after start capturing the ui is locked, i tried running it on a thread, and doesn't seem like it's thread safe.